# (Oracle SQL) Catching a unique constraint error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

This is my code:

```
Declare
  violation_of_constraint EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  -- (A FEW INSERTS HERE: A, B, C)
  SAVEPOINT X;
  -- (ANOTHER INSERT HERE: D)
  IF DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    ROLLBACK TO X;
    COMMIT;
    RAISE violation_of_constraint;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN violation_of_constraint THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value already exists');
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

When I run it (from the sql command line) I get this error at line 11:

```
expression is of wrong type (line 11 is "IF DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN")
```

What could it be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a nested `PL/SQL` Block, and handle exception in *EXCEPTION* BLOCK as `WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`...

It should *NOT* be `IF DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`

```
Declare
violation_of_constraint EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
  -- (A FEW INSERTS HERE: A, B, C)
  SAVEPOINT X;
  -- (ANOTHER INSERT HERE: D)
  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    ROLLBACK TO X;
    COMMIT;
    RAISE violation_of_constraint;
  END;
EXCEPTION
WHEN violation_of_constraint THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value already exists');
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked :) However sql command line only reports procedure completed successfully, it didn't display the message "value already exists". INSERT D actually has a duplicate key in a column where there is a unique key constraint... But I suppose this is a different problem ?

Comment: Oh.. you had `set serveroutput on` to enable `dbms_output` ?

Comment: Nop... where does it go ? Before the whole declaration I suppose ?

Comment: Oh thanks very much ! I've been trying to say thank you for a while now and my comment wouldn't go through, then realised it didn't have the minimum 15 characters :)