# exception handling in plsql procedure to handle insert giving unique constraint

Tags: plsql, exception, plsqldeveloper

I have an sql having multiple inserts but when I am running it is giving unique constraint for the first insert....and sql is skipping the other inserts.Can u help me with the exception handling for this scenario.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175894/oracle-sql-catching-a-unique-constraint-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Oracle SQL) Catching a unique constraint error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175894/oracle-sql-catching-a-unique-constraint-error)

Comment: By "an sql" do you mean a PL/SQL procedure or a multi-table insert statement? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#i2125362

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your insert statements in a BEGIN/END block with an exception handler to catch the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception. There you can do whatever you need to do or just ignore the error.

```
BEGIN
    -- first insert
    BEGIN
        Insert into myTab(ID,NAME) values (1,'name1');
    EXCEPTION 
        when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
            null; -- do something or ignore the error
    END;

    -- second insert
    BEGIN
        Insert into myTab(ID,NAME) values (2,'name2');
    EXCEPTION 
        when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
            null; -- do something or ignore the error
    END;
END;
```